# How to validate if a value doesn't exist in a table's row count using ruby ​capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

There is a column in my table that stores the active and inactive value in the STATUS column. I want to validate if when searching for the ACTIVE status if there are no INACTIVE records.
How do I scan this column and use expect to validate that no INACTIVE value has appeared?
And if it doesn't appear, I present a message like: puts 'no inactive record found in the list".
i tried this: page.all('.tvGrid tr').each do |tr| next unless tr.has_css?('td.Status', text: "ATIVO")

```
<div style="display:table-cell;">
    <table width="100%" class="tvGrid">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Id</th>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Código</th>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Descrição</th>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Centro Operacional</th>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'stvSetorAbastecimentos','1cfd','Modify',0,'','','');" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll">
                <td align="right" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap="">21</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">02</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">BARRETO PIRES</td>
                <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap="">Águas de Niterói/GSO</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">ATIVO</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'stvSetorAbastecimentos','1cfd','Modify',1,'','','');" class="tvRow tvRowEven tvRoll">
                <td align="right" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap="">41</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">03</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">CAFUBÁ PIRATININGA</td>
                <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap="">Águas de Niterói/GSO</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">ATIVO</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'stvSetorAbastecimentos','1cfd','Modify',2,'','','');" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll">
                <td align="right" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap="">42</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">04</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">CAVALÃO</td>
                <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap="">Águas de Niterói/GSO</td>
                <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">ATIVO</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the test? In Minitest you would do something like  `assert_select "td", {count: 0, text: "There are no inactive record in the list"}, "This page should not contain inactive records"`. RSpec has  the `have_content` matcher - `expect(page).to_not have_content "There are no inactive record in the list"`.

Comment: My problem is not knowing how to map the element to be able to do this control. I 
I tried the command to get only the active values ​​of the column but I'm still getting all the values.  page.all('.tvGrid td').each do |td|  
  puts td.text . I will update my call and show which attempts

Comment: Should you be doing this test via Capybara? Feels more like a controller test.

Comment: i tried this:   page.all('.tvGrid tr').each do |tr|
next unless tr.has_css?('td.Status', text: "ATIVO")
expect(tr).to have_css('td.status', text: "INATIVO")
puts 'no inactive record found in the list'
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to validate if when searching for the ACTIVE status if there are no INACTIVE records.

Since you want to test the data, not how it is formatted, this is better done as a [controller test](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers).

You can use [`rails-controller-testing`](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) to test what is passed to your views. `assigns` gives you access to instance variables which have been passed to your views.

```
test "should show only active records" do
  # Call the appropriate URL with the appropriate parameters
  get search_url, params: { active: true }

  # Check the right template is rendered
  assert_template 'records/index'

  # Check the correct data is passed to the view.
  assert_equal Record.active, assigns(:records)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, never used and I have to do this solution with ruby ​​and capybara.

Comment: I saw this, maybe I'm checking that the column should have Active I think it solves it. page.all('.tvGrid tr > td:nth-child(4)').each do |td|
    %w{ATIVO}.should include td.text

Comment: it seems this solved my life!!!  page.all('.tvGrid tr > td:nth-child(5)').each do |td|
    %w{INATIVO}.should include td.text
    puts td.text
end

Comment: @SilvioAulik That is a very fragile test and will break if a column is added, removed, or reordered. This is why it is better done as a controller test. If you must use capybara, and I would push back against that, I would advise to instead add CSS classes to the table cells which identify what is in the cell and find by that.